TextField data is not getting clear
When the user enters a password value and cancels the dialog, the dialog is pre-filled with the previous password, but the email is successfully cleared. However, the password is not cleared. If I remove the condition it.length <= 8 under the value change for the password, it works fine. I need to add validation to ensure that the user cannot enter a password with more than 8 or fewer than 8 characters.
Screen
 var reauthEmail by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
 var reauthPassword by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

      ReauthDialog(
            onDismiss = {
                showReauthDialog = false
                reauthEmail = ""
                reauthPassword = ""
            },
            onConfirm = {
                reauthErrorMessage = ""
                profileEditViewModel.reauthenticateUser(reauthEmail, reauthPassword, {
                    showReauthDialog = false
                    onReauthCompleted = true
                }, { errorMessage ->
                    reauthErrorMessage = errorMessage
                })
            },
            reauthEmail = reauthEmail,
            onReauthEmailChange = { reauthEmail = it },
            reauthPassword = reauthPassword,
            onReauthPasswordChange = {
                reauthPassword = it
            },
            reauthErrorMessage
        )
    }
    @Composable

    fun ReauthDialog(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    reauthEmail: String,
    onReauthEmailChange: (String) -> Unit,
    reauthPassword: String,
    onReauthPasswordChange: (String) -> Unit,
    reauthErrorMessage: String
) {
    var isEmailError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isPasswordError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


    AlertDialog(
        titleContentColor = Color.White,
        containerColor = Category_Indicator,
        onDismissRequest = {
            onReauthEmailChange("")
            onReauthPasswordChange("")
            Log.d("TAG", "ReauthDialog: $reauthPassword")
            isEmailError = false
            isPasswordError = false
            onDismiss()

        },
        title = { Text(text = "Reauthenticate") }, text = {
            Column {
                TextField(
                    value = reauthEmail,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = {
                        onReauthEmailChange(it)
                        isEmailError = !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(reauthEmail).matches()
                    },
                    label = { Text("Email") },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email, imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                    ),
                    supportingText = {
                        if (isEmailError) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Invalid email format",
                                color = Color.Red,
                                fontSize = 12.ssp,
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    isError = isEmailError,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        unfocusedContainerColor = Category_Indicator,
                        focusedContainerColor = Category_Indicator,
                        unfocusedTextColor = Color.White,
                        focusedTextColor = Color.White,
                        errorTextColor = Color.White,
                        cursorColor = Color.White,
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                        errorContainerColor = Category_Indicator,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color.White,
                        focusedLabelColor = Color.White,

                        )
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.sdp))

                var passwordVisibility: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                TextField(
                    visualTransformation = if (passwordVisibility) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                    trailingIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            passwordVisibility = !passwordVisibility
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                tint = Color.White,
                                painter = painterResource(id = if (passwordVisibility) R.drawable.ic_show_password else R.drawable.ic_hide_password),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(20.sdp)
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    value = reauthPassword,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = {
                        if (it.length <= 8) {
                            onReauthPasswordChange(it)
                            isPasswordError = it.length < 8
                        }

                    },
                    label = { Text("Password") },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password, imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    supportingText = {
                        if (isPasswordError) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Password must be at least 8 characters",
                                color = Color.Red,
                                fontSize = 12.ssp,
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    isError = isPasswordError,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        unfocusedContainerColor = Category_Indicator,
                        focusedContainerColor = Category_Indicator,
                        unfocusedTextColor = Color.White,
                        focusedTextColor = Color.White,
                        errorTextColor = Color.White,
                        cursorColor = Color.White,
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                        errorContainerColor = Category_Indicator,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color.White,
                        focusedLabelColor = Color.White,
                    )
                )

                Text(text = reauthErrorMessage, color = Color.Red)
            }
        }, confirmButton = {
            Button(
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = Purple_Button,
                    contentColor = Color.White
                ),
                enabled = ((reauthEmail.isNotEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(reauthEmail)
                    .matches())
                        && (reauthPassword.isNotEmpty() && reauthPassword.length == 8)),
                onClick = onConfirm
            ) {
                Text("Confirm")
            }
        }, dismissButton = {

            Button(
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = Color.White,
                    contentColor = Color.Black
                ), onClick = {
                    onDismiss()

                }
            ) {
                Text("Cancel")

            }
        })
}


Please try to optimize the code to show only the relevant parts. All the colors are not really needed to reproduce the issue. At the same time, the logic deciding whether the ReauthDialog is shown or not is completely missing. Please edit your post and provide a minimal reproducible example.

@BenjyTec Can you help with this link? It would be great.

@BenjyTec Can you help with this link? It would be great.

There sometimes are issues when using the TextField overload that takes a String as input. The underlying problem is that the onValueChange seems to be fired one additional time after the TextField looses focus. So what happens is

You reset all values
You hide the Dialog
The TextField looses focus
onValueChange is fired one more time with the previous value

It works when you change your TextField to use a TextFieldValue instance instead of a String.
Please replace the respective String occurences using TextFieldValues, then it will work as expected:
var reauthPassword by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

and
onDismiss = {
    showReauthDialog = false
    reauthEmail = ""
     reauthPassword = TextFieldValue("")
},

and
@Composable
fun ReauthDialog(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    reauthEmail: String,
    onReauthEmailChange: (String) -> Unit,
    reauthPassword: TextFieldValue,
    onReauthPasswordChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    reauthErrorMessage: String
) {
    //...

    onValueChange = {
        if (it.text.length <= 8) {
            onReauthPasswordChange(it)
            isPasswordError = it.text.length < 8
        }
    },

    //...

    Button(
        enabled = ((reauthEmail.isNotEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(reauthEmail)
            .matches())
                && (reauthPassword.text.isNotEmpty() && reauthPassword.text.length == 8)),
        onClick = onConfirm
    ) {
        Text("Confirm")
    }
}

However, I agree that this is really strange behavior that never should be designed that way. You can create an issue on the Google Issue Tracker to report the problem.

The issue is that the onValueChange handler for the password TextField stops updating the state when the password length exceeds 8 characters. If the state isn't updated to an empty string, it remains preserved even after closing and reopening the dialog
You can use a LaunchedEffect to reset the state when the dialog is shown.
@Composable
fun ReauthDialog(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    reauthEmail: String,
    onReauthEmailChange: (String) -> Unit,
    reauthPassword: String,
    onReauthPasswordChange: (String) -> Unit,
    reauthErrorMessage: String
) {
    var isEmailError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isPasswordError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var passwordVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        onReauthEmailChange("")
        onReauthPasswordChange("")
        isEmailError = false
        isPasswordError = false
        passwordVisibility = false
    }
  //reset of the code
}


In onDismiss, the OP calls reauthPassword = "", so I thought it will be reset no matter which code is placed in onValueChange. Did I understand this wrong?
